# upload photo -> wrong album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-php-sdk, photo, facebook-page

I'm trying to upload a photo to an album of a fan-page using the php sdk:

```
$this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$fields['image']        = '@'.realpath($source);
$fields['message']      = $message;
$fields['access_token'] = $this->settings['access_token'];

$return = $this->facebook->api($albumID.'/photos', 'POST', $fields);
```

- `$this->facebook` is an object of the facebook SDK
- `$albumID` is the ID of an album that belongs to the fan-page
- My app has the permissions   `publish_stream`, `user_photos`, `manage_pages` and some more

The upload works, but the picture gets placed in the album `[myAppName] Photos` that belongs to the page owner.

How can I accomplish, that the photo gets uploaded to the specified album?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, to use the `id`, that you get via the graph-API.
Not the AID, not the object_id (via FQL).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Page's `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) uploading photos to Page's Album, otherwise content will be published to user owning active `access_token`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now facebook created a new album called `[myAppName] Photos` for the **page** and saves the uploads there.

Comment: Well, this is probably means that `$albumID` is empty. Try to dump it before issuing the request.

Comment: I checked this again: it's not empty and it is a valid album ID.